# VSTS/TFS Extension TFS getFields()

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Below mentioned Api doesnot work with TFS 2017 on-premises version but works fine with OnlineVisualStudio. Is there any workaround to make it work in TFS 2017 on-premises version.

```
 import * as WitClient from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient";

GetWorkitemFieldsList(): IPromise<Contracts.WorkItemField[]> {
    let svc = this;
    var deferred = $.Deferred<Contracts.WorkItemField[]>();
    WitClient.getClient().getFields(VSS.getWebContext().project.id).then(function (fieldsList) {
        deferred.resolve(fieldsList)
    }, (reason) => {
        alert(reason);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

}

I want to access the TFS Fields without having Active Workitem.

Comment: In TFS im getting the error "Sequence contains no matching element"

Comment: If this works well on VSTS and not work with TFS2017, it's make sense, some vsts api is new which do not compatible/ work on old TFS version. There is no any workaround for this, could you try to use some client api.

Comment: okay. Thanks Patrick